# NP Class Definition of a Certificate

Tags: np, nondeterminism, polynomial-time

Given the definition for all x ∈ Σ∗

> x ∈ L ⇔ ∃ u ∈ Σ∗ with |u| ≤ p(|x|) and M(x, u) = 1

Lets say the input x = ababab

Then the certificate u shouldn't be longer than p(|x|).

But what would be p(|x|)? In my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, $p(|x|)$ denotes any function polynomial in the length of $x$.

Asking what $p$ is when $x=ababab$ is like asking "What is the running time on input ababab?" without specifying the algorithm you want to know the running time of (or specifying the problem the algorithm is supposed to solve, for that matter). It's a meaningless question. $p$ should be specified as part of proving that a particular language $L$ is in NP. You can't talk about what $p$ is without first defining a language.

If, for instance, you wanted to prove that Vertex Cover is in NP, then for a given graph $G$ and integer $k$, the certificate $u$ could be a vertex cover of $G$ of size at most $k$. Such a certificate would have size equal to the number of vertices of the graph (one bit per vertex) and thus $p$ could simply be the identity function. $M$ would be a machine that verifies that a given certificate $u$ is indeed a valid vertex cover.

Comment: Could you give a specific example for such a function, when x=ababab ?

Comment: The function $p(n) = C$ works, for any $C \geq 0$.

Comment: sorry maybe i didnt stated it right, t think p was defined as the polynomial length, so the polynomial length of |x|, but what the hell is a polynomial length?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the polynomial length of |x|" - that's not valid English. $|x|$ is a number. For your $ababab$ example, it's $6$. $p$ is a function, and $p(|x|)$ is that function evaluated at $|x|$ (in your specific case, you'd compare whether the length of $u$ is less than $p(6)$). $p$ has to be a polynomial function, so $p(x)$ could be $x^2$ or $x^3$ or $x^{100}$ (etc...) but it wouldn't be allowed to be something not-polynomial like $2^x$ or $x!$.

Comment: ok, thats great I am almost there... and who specifies this polynomial function? does this function has something in common with the turing machine itself? meaning is the time or space complexity equally this function? or are this two complete different things?

Comment: It isn't specified by anybody. A language $L$ is in NP if there exist $M,p$ for which the definition in your post is satisfied. You're free to pick $p$ yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A language $L$ is in NP if there exists a polynomial $p$ and a Turing machine $M$ running in polynomial time such that
$$
x \in L \text{ iff there exists } u \in \Sigma^* \text{ with } |u| \leq p(|x|) \text{ such that } M(x,u) = 1.
$$
Asking what is $p$ is exactly the same as asking what is $M$. When proving that a language is in NP, we have to specify both $p$ and $M$.

Comment: sorry maybe I didnt stated it right, I think p was defined as the polynomial length, so the polynomial length of |x|, but what the hell is a polynomial length?

Comment: I suggest you forget about your definition, and stick to mine.

Comment: I do not see a difference in your definition to mine

Comment: My definition doesn't contain the phrase *polynomial length*, which you don't like.

Comment: I'm not sure if I dont like it, I just dont know what it is.

Comment: The meaning is what appears in my definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79336/discussion-between-simplesystems-and-yuval-filmus).